# Sorting Order of Freebase MQL Read Service results

Tags: freebase, mql

I am trying to get a list of items using a list of MIDs

Previously I asked this question [Array of Freebase MIDs and sending multiple queries to freebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613103/array-of-freebase-mids-and-sending-multiple-queries-to-freebase)

So my MQL query looks like this now:

```
[{
  "mid": null,
  "name": null,
  "topics:mid|=":[
    "/m/045c7b",
    "/m/0d6lp",
    "/m/021ympy",
    ...
    ]
}]
```

[Sample MQL Query URL](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1-sandbox/mqlread?query=%5B%7B%22mid%22:null,%22name%22:null,%22topics:mid%7C=%22:%5B%22/m/0tc7%22,%22/m/0h7pj%22,%22/m/02v406%22,%22/m/0gn30%22,%22/m/0m8_v%22,%22/m/015lhm%22,%22/m/0c1pj%22,%22/m/0c0k1%22,%22/m/01g969%22,%22/m/0hqly%22%5D%7D%5D)

However, the default order seems to be based on something like index or timestamp. I would like the order of the results to mirror the order the MIDs are listed in the query - is this possible? If so, any hints on what the MQL would look like would be awesome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with MQL - you'll have to do the sorting client-side. For what it's worth, the default order is undefined, so don't rely on it for anything.